# Set template in layout handle for Adminhtml

Tags: magento, layout, handle, adminhtml

In the backend of my Magento Webshop I want to set a template for the blocks of System->Config. Therefore I use the layout handle of the `Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController` which is `adminhtml_system_config_index` I think. The problem is, nothing happens. Even if want to remove blocks, nothing happens:

```
<adminhtml_system_config_index>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>myModule/template.phtml</template>
        </action>   
    </reference>
</adminhtml_system_config_index>
```

OR removing block:

```
<adminhtml_system_config_index>
    <remove name="left" />
</adminhtml_system_config_index>
```

What am I doing wrong? I even tried `system_config_index` as layout handle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're doing three possible things wrong here.

**First Tip**: Are you editing the right XML file?

A lot of common layout problems come from the XML file you're editing not being the XML file that's loaded by the system.  Switch on developer mode in your site, set `display_errors` to `1`, and then deliberately introduce a non well formed error into your XML files and try to load the page.

```
<!-- note the trailing greater than sign at the end -->
<adminhtml_system_config_index>
    ...
</adminhtml_system_config_index> >
```

If the page loads without error, then you're not loading the XML file you think you are.

**Second Tip**: Are you using the correct layout handle?

I'm not sure you are. Despite the fact the default system configuration page uses the `index` action, this action actually forwards the page to the `edit` action.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php
public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_forward('edit');
}
```

Forwarding means there's an internal redispatch, but no http redirect.  That means your actual handle is

```
`adminhtml_system_config_edit`
```

This is why I use (disclaimer: and built, and sell) [Commerce Bug](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug-2).  The Layout tab always displays the current handles, and I can avoid making assumptions that send me down the wrong path.

[image: image of layout table showing Commerce Bug handles]

Third Tip: Are you confusing the block named `left` with the left hand column?

In general, Magento's container blocks (`left`, `content`, `right`, etc.) are **not** template blocks.  Instead they're container blocks (`text/list` blocks to be precise) that hold and multiple template blocks.

This is another place I use Commerce Bug, [specifically the new Graphviz feature](http://alanstorm.com/find_magento_block_name).  This will show you the block structure for any particular page.  In a factory default system, you'd see something like this for the System Configuration page

[image]

As you can see, the left block has no template, so changing its template will have no effect.  The block you probably want is `left.child1`.

**Fourth Tip**: Is the block you're trying to modify added by the layout XML.

Without getting too deeply into layout rendering (which would [take a book](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout)), there are some block which are added **after** the layout generates all its blocks.  If this is the case, your block will not be available in layout XML files.

If you look at the `editAction` method, you can see that the tabs block is added **after** `loadLayout` is called (look for `adminhtml/system_config_tabs`).  This means it won't be available in layout xml files.

```
public function editAction()
{
    //...    

    //the `loadLayout` method call creates blocks based on layout XML files
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->_setActiveMenu('system/config');
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('menu')->setAdditionalCacheKeyInfo(array($current));

    $this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('System'), Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('System'),
        $this->getUrl('*/system'));

    //this line add the `child1` block to the layout. (child one is the 
    //name chosen since the block has no explicit name
    $this->getLayout()->getBlock('left')
        ->append($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/system_config_tabs')->initTabs());

    //...
```

This means you can't modify the template of this block from a layout XML file.  You'll need to use a custom module that listens for an appropriate event and then makes your changes via PHP.  I'd try the event `controller_action_layout_render_before` or `controller_action_layout_render_before_adminhtml_system_config_edit` with PHP code that looks something like

```
$block = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('child1');
if($block)
{
    $block->setTemplate('foo.phtml');
}
```

Comment: Update: So I debugged into it. The layout xml is loaded correctly. It gets stucked in `Mage_Core_Model_Layout` (Enterprise 1.12.0.2). If I use `left.child1`: line 311 `if(!empty($block))` will not succed, so the `setTemplate` will not be called. If I use `left`, it succeeds, but as you already said, you can't set a template on 'text/list'. So I am wondering why `$block = $this->getBlock($parentName);` with $parentName is `left.child1` returns false?
I tried to reference the `footer` which worked because it gets created directly. Why can't I do this with the left hand column?

Comment: @tester Updated the answer.  It looks like that block is added via PHP **after** the layout XML renders, which means its not available via layout xml files.

Comment: one final queston: how can I add a css file to this `left.child1`?
I tried `$block->addCss('...');` and `Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->addCss('...');`, but nothing worked. UPDATE: I found the solution: addCss works on `head` block.